# Message Enricher in Mule

Tags: mule

Trying to understand when to use Message Enricher in Mule? Can someone explains with real usage would be great. I already gone through mule documentation examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mule message enricher is best used in the case when you do not to lose your existing payload.

For example, let's consider, you need to **call a DB** in the **middle of the flow** and by doing this you will loose your current payload with the data from the DB and you don't want this to happen.

So, here you need your DB component **wrapped** with message enricher. By doing that you will get the data from DB as well as you will **not lose** your existing current payload.

```
 <enricher target="#[flowVars.recordFound]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
     <db:select config-ref="Derby_Configuration1" doc:name="DB_Details">
       <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from Table1]]></db:parameterized-query>
     </db:select>
</enricher>
```

Since message enricher takes a copy of the current payload, your existing payload will not lost
For more idea you can refer here:- http://www.slideshare.net/anir37/mule-message-enricher

Answer (score 1):

Message Enricher will be used to store the data and to check that data in future processing like if you have to do batch processing so that it has to check the data whether present or not in first batch, if not we can insert that data in second batch.

It is like enrich the message which does not have in source system.

Answer (score 1):

One common scenario involves the need to enrich an incoming message with information that isn’t provided by the source system. You can use a content enricher if the target system needs more information than the source system can provide.

Consider a message from a source system contains a zip code but the target system needs the two letter state. A message enricher can be used to lookup the state using the zip code from an enrichment resource. The enricher calls out to the enrichment resource with the current message (containing the zip code) then enriches the current message with the result.

This is a very simple flow with one-way inbound and outbound endpoints, and which acts as part of an order processing pipeline. This flow uses an enricher to add a state flow variable to the current message with the state that the stateLookup endpoint returns.  The ‘target’ attribute defines how the current message is enriched using a MessageEnricher which uses the same syntax as expression evaluators.

Answer (score 0):

Mule Enricher is a component, whole idea of using an enricher is to maintain the payload transaction intact and use it's content to apply some logic and store the result in a variable.

e.g. can be a xml payload, used to derive a complex logic result like discount calculation and then result of it can be stored in a variable and can be used further.

Answer (score 0):

To add to these answers, you may also set the returning message (e.g. payload) to either payload, flow variables and outbound properties by simply defining the source and target within the Message Enricher.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the **Message Enricher** in Mule is to carry the same payload even after calling another flow by using flow reference.

- Use Case: If you wanna use the same payload data through out the flow then you should go for **Message Enricher**

As you can see in the attached screenshot, here I have two flow references one is under **Message Enricher** i.e the Message Enricher flow reference will prevent the payload to be overridden by the payload from the referenced flow(overridenFlow), the original payload is maintained so that it can be used further

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9HK0.png)

After second flow reference the payload is overridden and original payload can't be accessed further.

Answer (score 0):

Message enricher is mainly used to extract something(eg. xpath) from payload and store it into flow/session variable, without actually changing the payload.

More advantages:
1) The source can be anything(i.e. payload, variables etc)
2) The source can also be modified to be able to extract info from it.
3) Multiple sources and target option is also available.

Also, as only one component can reside inside Message Enricher. Use of processor chain is recommended if more components are needed to reside inside Message Enricher.

Answer (score 0):

Message Enricher in Mule is used to carry the same payload even after calling another flow by using flow reference.

Example use case: If you are taking data from some SaaS application and then want to store that data in Database, such that there is no duplicate entry in the Database. In this case you can check for Duplicate Data with the help of message Enricher before inserting it into Database.

Answer (score 0):

Message enricher is one of the important components with Mulesoft. There are various scenarios in which you can use the message enricher component.

When synchronizing data between data sources, you often check to see if a record already exists in the target resource.

If you simply add an endpoint to query the target resource first before adding it, the response will become the payload. This is not what you want!

You want the external call to act as an enrichment of the existing message with the original payload retained.

Answer (score -1):

Message Enricher in Mule is used to carry the same payload even after calling another flow by using flow reference.